# python load A.so file whose some function defined in B.so file

Tags: python, ctypes, .so

I am trying to use python to load some .so files with ctypes modules, but I get some trouble.
when I load A.so file, it occur an error of "undefined symbol: xxxxxx(a function)". and I find this function is defined in B.so file.
so how can I load A.so file

Comment: if A and B are not in the same folder, add B's folder's path to environment variable "LD_LIBRARY_PATH". you can verify it using `ldd A.so`

Comment: Is *A.so* depending on *B.so*? Based on your error, it doesn't seem to be. So the 2 seem to be independent (in this case *A* expects that *xxxx* to be magically defined - which doesn't seem a good thing). Anyway, try loading *B.so* before *A*.

Answer (score 0):

if A.so depending on B.so,i also encountered a similar problem.I loaded A.so on jupter,

but the OSError:
`B.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Fortunately,my probleam was finally solved,i loaded B.so before loading A.so,and if you just call the function from A.so ,you don't even have to define a new variables to take on B.so.
eg:

```
cdll.LoadLibrary('B.so')
myLib = cdll.LoadLibrary('A.s0')
myLib.function()
```

Different platforms may have different results, hope to help you!